# Wrong propagation of MX record

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

We have set a MX record in our DNS records as follows:

```
Type: MX
TTL: 1800
Name: @
Priority: 10
Hostname: webmail.ourdomain.fr
```

However, when we check the propagation by for example https://www.whatsmydns.net/#MX/ourdomain.fr, we see that the hostname is `mail.ourdomain.fr.ourdomain.fr`.

Does anyone know what may be the problem?

PS: we have also 3 A records as follows, is it the reason of confusion?

```
mail    A   1800    5.100.152.xxx
webmail A   1800    5.100.152.xxx
webmail.ourdomain.fr    A   1800    5.100.152.xxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the full stop at the end of the hostname.